# Biztalk ESB Practices is failing

Tags: biztalk, esb

This is a weird situation for me. I accidently deleted all rows in the following tables.

1. bts_orchestration_binding
2. bts_send_port.

By doing so, I lost all my custom ports and bindings. The MAIN part is I lost ESB toolkit related send ports as well.
Now my setup is misconfigured.

Please suggest any way how can I fix this issue. I tried to re-run the setup but no-use. getting foreign key errors. 
Is uninstall of whole esb-toolkit and install could be the only solution? pls suggest.

Comment: If you've deleted the data then it's gone. I don't see how anyone could help you recover from this without posting a sql statement to insert all the lost esb toolkit data. Just re-install it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try querying your transaction log:

```
SELECT
    [Current LSN],
    [Transaction ID],
    [Operation],
    [Context],
    [AllocUnitName]
FROM fn_dbLog(NULL, NULL)
WHERE [Operation] = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
```

From this article: http://sqlbak.com/blog/recover-deleted-data-in-sql-server/

also see [Undelete recently deleted rows sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786028/undelete-recently-deleted-rows-sql-server)
and http://raresql.wordpress.com/2011/10/22/how-to-recover-deleted-data-from-sql-sever/

But I would just re-install esb toolkit if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

These tables are located in the BizTalk Management database (BizTalkMgmtDb). If you configured the [Backup BizTalk Server job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546765.aspx), you could try to restore this database as this job makes log backups every 15 minutes by default and full backups once a day.

More info about restoring the BizTalk databases can be found on MSDN: [How to Restore Your Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546753.aspx)