# Revert a certain change in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently working on a WinForms solution where users can add or alter data in the database by filling out a certain form. When a user made a couple of changes to the data, by filling out `x` number of forms, I want the user to be able to revert any of the changes he's made to the data (in the current session).

What I'm planning on doing is giving the user a list of changes he's made (either by timestamp or creating an object which displays some more information) and letting the user choose which change he'd like to revert. I was thinking about saving the changes in a dictionary as follows:

```
var changes = new Dictionary<KEY, List<Entity>>();
```

The key could just be the timestamp of the change or any other identifying property. The value would be the original values prior to the changes.

I'm not very familiar with EF and have seen some solutions where reverting is done by using other methods given by EF.

Any help in how to go about this is much appreciated!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sql server

Comment: SQL Server keeps log files that you can use.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786028/undelete-recently-deleted-rows-sql-server

Comment: I only have to track changes for the current session. I feel like querying the log files would be a bit much for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Do you want to duplicate what is already being done by the server?  Is the current session one thread or multiple threads?  Do you have one instance of Entity or multiple?

Comment: The current session is one thread. A change could in its current form could mean an update to a thousand entities in the database. This might simply be changing a bool from true to false, but could also be adding or deleting 1000 rows to/from the database.